# Using entity framework 6 - Code First approach Is there a way to add Associations on Comma Separated Ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, associations

I am using EF6

Entity A has an identity property AID and another entity B has a property AIds which is a comma separated string of AID values

e.q. like

**Entity A**

```
AID ANAME
--------------
 1    A1
 2    A2
```

**Entity B**

```
BID  BNAME   AIDs
------------------
 1    A1     1,2
 2    A2     2
```

I need to introduce a navigational property `IList<A>` in `B` and vice versa. Can we do this with code first approach?

---

**Update**

I also have property in B AIDLIST that returns me list

Comment: Don't store **multiple values** in a single cell! This is a horribly bad practice in relational databases - and it causes nothing but grief and troubles - just **don't do it!**

Comment: can't help. DB has legacy structure.